# Проблема с Jquery UI Autocomplete в Safari на мобильном

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, jquery-ui

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. На сайте(форуме) используется Jquery UI Autocomplete для поиска ников при наборе сообщения. Пишем @ потом 3 буквы и идет запрос на сервер и предлагает варианты. Проблема в мобильном safari - если вводить латинские буквы - то все отлично отрабатывает, если вводишь ник русскими - не работает и после этого перестает работать и на латинице. На андроиде(хром) и на пк(хром, опера, мозила) все норм с обоими языками. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным, буду очень признателен?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему самостоятельно. Причина оказалась в том, что в safari - keyCode - русских букв приходил как "0" - из-за этого не проходила проверка на наличие кода